# Postgres trigram search is slow

Tags: postgresql, indexing, trigram

I have a table with around 3 million rows.
I created single gin index on multiple columns of the table.

```
CREATE INDEX search_idx ON customer USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops, id gin_trgm_ops, data gin_trgm_ops)
```

I am running following query (simplified to use single column in criteria) but it takes around 4 seconds:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT c.id, similarity(c.name, 'john') sml
FROM customer c WHERE
c.name % 'john'
ORDER BY sml DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The output query plan is:

```
Limit (cost=9255.12..9255.14 rows=10 width=30) (actual time=3771.661..3771.665 rows=10 loops=1)
  -> Sort (cost=9255.12..9260.43 rows=2126 width=30) (actual time=3771.659..3771.661 rows=10 loops=1)
       Sort Key: (similarity((name)::text, 'john'::text)) DESC
       Sort Method: top-N heapsort Memory: 26kB
       -> Bitmap Heap Scan on customer c (cost=1140.48..9209.18 rows=2126 width=30) (actual time=140.665..3770.478 rows=3605 loops=1)
            Recheck Cond: ((name)::text % 'john'::text)
            Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 939598
            Heap Blocks: exact=158055 lossy=132577
            -> Bitmap Index Scan on search_idx (cost=0.00..1139.95 rows=2126 width=0) (actual time=105.609..105.610 rows=458131 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'john'::text)
Planning Time: 0.102 ms
```

I fail to understand that why the rows are not SORTED and LIMITed to 10 when retrieved from the search_idx in first step, and afterwards only 10 rows are fetched from the customer table (instead of 2126 rows)

Any ideas how can this query be made faster.
I tried gist index but i see no performance gains.
I also tried increasing the work_mem from 4MB to 32MB and I can see improvement of 1 sec but not more.
Also I noticed that even if I remove c.id in SELECT clause, postgres does not perform index only scan and still joins with main table.

Thanks for the help.

Update1:
After Laurenz Albe suggestion below the query performance increased and it is now around 600 ms. Plan looks like this now:

```
Subquery Scan on q  (cost=0.41..78.29 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=63.150..574.536 rows=10 loops=1)
  Filter: ((q.name)::text % 'john'::text)
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..78.16 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=63.148..574.518 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using search_name_idx on customer c  (cost=0.41..2232864.76 rows=287182 width=40) (actual time=63.146..574.513 rows=10 loops=1)
              Order By: ((name)::text <-> 'john'::text)
Planning Time: 42.671 ms
Execution Time: 585.554 ms
```

Comment: Your query is not written in way that could use the KNN GiST feature.

Answer (score 2):

To get the 10 closest matches with index support, you should create a GiST index and query like this:

```
SELECT id, sml
FROM (SELECT c.id,
             c.name,
             similarity(c.name, 'john') sml
      FROM customer c
      ORDER BY c.name <-> 'john'
      LIMIT 10) AS q
WHERE name % 'john';
```

The subquery can use the GiST index, and the outer query eliminates all results that do not exceed the `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I tried this and it seems the query time has reduced consdierably. Its down to 600ms. Can it be improved further?

Comment: Also how should the query be written if there are multiple similarilty columns e.g. name, id, city, etc. I tried to to `least` function on distance operator result, but then it does not use index.

Comment: Multiple columns -> `UNION ALL`

Comment: I tried `UNION ALL` with 3 columns the query time increased to 1800 ms :(
Seems like thats the best we can get from `GIST`

Comment: Should I ecplore the `tsvector` route? i.e. put those columns in a document. and use `tsvector` queries?

Comment: Full text search does not have a concept of similarity. It only finds exact matches. If you look for a short strings like "john", the search is often less efficient; that is in the nature of things. You could concatenate several columns in a `GENERATED` column and search in that with `LIKE 'string1%string2%string3'`. But that would be better with a GIN index, and you couldn't use the KNN approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Referring https://alexklibisz.com/2022/02/18/optimizing-postgres-trigram-search.html

I updated the query to use `word_similarity` with multicolumn GIST index and it improved performance alot.

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
WITH input AS (SELECT 'new york' AS search)
SELECT *
FROM customer, input
WHERE
(
    input.search <% id
    OR input.search <% name
    OR input.search <% city
)
ORDER BY
input.search <<-> id,
input.search <<-> name,
input.search <<-> city
LIMIT 10
```

Explain plan showsindex only scan.